# Rigorous derivation of $d\Pi$ for stock with continuous dividend

Tags: black-scholes, black-scholes-pde

Suppose we are holding a replicating portfolio $\Pi_t$ of long an option $f(S,t)$ and short some stock, so $$\Pi_t=f(S_t,t)-\Delta_t S_t$$  Suppose the stock follows geometric Brownian motion and pays continuous dividends at rate $q$, so $$d S_t = S_t((\mu-q)dt + \sigma dW_t$$  Naively, $$d\Pi_t = d f(S_t,t)-\Delta_t dS_t$$  However, because the stock pays a dividend, common sense and the literature tell us that $$d\Pi_t=df(S_t,t)-\Delta_t dS_t-\Delta_t S_t dt$$

**Question:** How do we rigorously arrive at the total derivative for $d\Pi_t$ which includes extra term $-\Delta_t S_t dt$, given that we know $\Pi_t=f(S_t,t)-\Delta_t S_t$, without appeal to common sense i.e., from the equations, without recalling the mechanics of how the stock works?  Because, naively, I would not include the extra term, if I just knew the equation defining $\Pi_t$ and nothing about the mechanics of the stock.

Comment: Hi @Lars Ericson. What you are asking is little paradoxical to me. How can one write the equations of something "without knowing how it works"? More specifically, holding a stock is not a self-financing strategy: as a dividend gets paid this gets credited to your cash account. To avoid arbitrage opportunities, when that happens the price of stock gets amputated from the dividend amount (this is the $-qS_tdt$ part of the stock dynamics). The value of a dividend-paying stock thus differs from the value of a strategy consisting of holding that stock (in the latter dividends pop up as cash).

Comment: In other words: if you hold $\Delta_t$ stocks at $t$ (value $\Delta_t S_t$, which you hold for a small period of time $dt$ over which the stock pays a div yield $qdt$, the resulting position at $t+dt$ is worth $\Delta_t S_{t+dt} + \Delta _t S_t q dt$. Hence the infinitesimal variation of total value is indeed: $\Delta_t dS_t + \Delta_t S_t q dt = \Delta_t S_t (\mu dt + \sigma dW_t)$. Again the difference lies in the value of the stock vs. the value of a portfolio consisting of holding it. A difference which only exists if holding the asset is not a self-financing strategy.

Comment: [This writeup](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~stecher/425/Sp12/optionsForDividendStocks.pdf) has $dS=S((\mu - q) dt + \sigma dW)$ and $\Pi=f-\Delta S$ and then jumps to $d \Pi = df - \Delta dS - q S \Delta dt$ instead of $d \Pi=df-\Delta dS$.  Since the total derivative $dS$ is already stated, I was confused how the extra term $q S \Delta dt$ comes into being, as the total derivative is already stated as $dS=S((\mu - q) dt + \sigma dW)$ , not $dS=S((\mu - q) dt + \sigma dW) + q S dt$.  Basically the extra $q S dt$ popping up in the $d \Pi$ looked like magic, aside from "knowing how it works".

Comment: It's not a total derivative it's an Itô differential. It describes how the price of the stock will change over an infinitesimal period of time at order 1 in $dt$. And indeed you start with $\Pi = f - \Delta S$ and as time passes your make/lose $d\Pi = df - \Delta dS - \Delta qS dt$. The first term on the RHS is because the option price changed, the second term on the RHS is because the stock price has changed (according to the given $dS$)... the third is because this stock has paid dividends. $\Pi=\sum_i a_i X_i \to d\Pi = \sum_i a_i dX_i$ only holds for self-financing portfolios.

Comment: From a pure math perspective, ignoring the financial context, can you explain the difference between a total derivative and an Itô differential?  I'm trying to separate the math from the application.

Comment: You understand the difference between a derivative and a differential? Well starting from there and oversimplifying, the Ito differential is the extension of the differential of standard calculus for a function of a random variable. It's oversimplified because the notation only makes sense with regards to its integrated version best known as Ito stochastic integral (and indeed for functions of stochastic processes of infinite variation, you cannot define an integral in the usual sense). But again, I don't think the problem is here. The problem IMO is to reckon that $S$ (...)

Comment: is represents the price or value of a stock. So holding it you'll effectively win/lose money depending on how it evolves ($dS$ term) but you will also receive any capital distributions such as dividends (other term). Here the dividends are related to the price through a continuous div yield but it could also be a one shot cash amount for instance. Of course the two (dividend model and stock price dynamics) are intrinsically linked through no arbitrage assumptions.

Comment: There seems to be some elision in the notation, i.e. aspects of the financial model which are not fully expressed in the mathematical notation.  I've tried to narrow this aspect down in a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397127/what-is-the-difference-between-a-total-derivative-and-an-ito-differential) on Math Exchange.

Comment: Hopefully someone will answer your concerns. I'm sorry but I can't help much more I feel like I have said everything I could to help. But I'm probably failing at understanding the exact point which troubles you. Anyway, you have marked the answer as accepted so this will not attract more answers.

Comment: The $dS_t$ notation is formally defined as syntactic sugar for the Itô integral notation.  I will try re-doing the derivation of BS eqn using an integral formulation so that there is no notational confusion between total derivatives and Itô differentials.  I will try to un-mark the answer below as accepted because it introduces measure theory notation and concepts which I think are not needed to go from the process for a dividend-paying stock to the BS eqn.  I am looking for shortest clear passage from $\Pi=f-\Delta S$ to $d \Pi = df-\Delta dS -\Delta q S dt$.

Comment: Or let me put it a different way: Suppose you were writing a program in Mathematica or Maple to compute $d\Pi$.  The program is given as input $\{\Pi=f-\Delta S, dS=\alpha dt + \sigma dW\}$ in one case and outputs $d\Pi=df-\Delta dS$.  Then it is given $\{\Pi=f-\Delta S, dS=\alpha dt + \sigma dW, \alpha=\mu-q\}$, and in this case it outputs $d\Pi=df-\Delta dS-q S dt$.  How do you write that program?  Do you see my confusion now?  I am thinking strictly in terms of what can be written into a file, passed to a program, and written out to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S^0_t = e^{rt}$ be the money market account.

Consider you short a derivative $P_t$ and hedge it with cash and stock.
$$
  \Pi_t =  \Delta^0_t S^0_t + \Delta_t S_t - P_t
$$
At time $t+dt$, the portfolio is
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pi_{t+dt} &=& \Delta^0_t S^0_{t+dt} + \Delta_t S_{t+dt} + \Delta_t q_t S_t dt - P_{t+dt} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Where $\Delta_t q_t S_t dt$ corresponds to the dividend received. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pi_{t+dt} 
  &=& (1+rdt)\Delta^0_t S^0_{t} + \Delta_t S_{t+dt} - P_{t+dt} \\ 
  &=& (1+rdt)( \Pi_t - \Delta_t S_t + P_t ) + \Delta_t S_{t+dt} + \Delta_t q_t S_t - P_{t+dt} \\ 
  &=& (1+rdt)( \Pi_t - \Delta_t S_t + P_t ) + \Delta_t S_{t+dt} + \Delta_t q_t S_t - P_{t+dt} 
\end{eqnarray*}
This can be rewritten
\begin{eqnarray*}
  d\Pi_{t}-r\Pi_t &=& \Delta_t (dS_{t} - (r-q)S_tdt) - (dP_{t} - rP_tdt)  
\end{eqnarray*}

Assume the stock price has dynamic
$$
  \frac{dS_t}{S_t} = \mu dt + \sigma dW^\mathbb{P}_t
$$
under the real-world measure $\mathbb{P}$ (the drift could even be stochastic here). We search for the price in the form $P_t = P(t,S_t)$. Applying Ito, one finds
\begin{eqnarray*}
  dP_{t} &=&  \partial_tPdt + \partial_SP dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\partial^2_SP dt
\end{eqnarray*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
  d\Pi_{t}-r\Pi_t &=& (\Delta_t - \partial_SP) dS_{t} - \Delta_t S_t (r-q)dt) - \partial_tPdt - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\partial^2_SP dt + rP(t,S_t)dt)  
\end{eqnarray*}
In order to kill the stochastic term we should choose $\Delta_t = \partial_SP$. We end up with a risk-less portfolio with PnL
\begin{eqnarray*}
  d\Pi_{t}-r\Pi_t &=& -\left(\partial_tP + (r-q)S_t \partial_SP + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\partial^2_SP - rP \right)dt 
\end{eqnarray*}
By absence of arbitrage, this has to be 0 otherwise we could make a guaranteed profit without taking any risk. So the right hand side is the diffusion equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \partial_tP + (r-q)S_t \partial_SP + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S_t^2\partial^2_SP dt = rP
\end{eqnarray*}
This is a diffusion equation (the Black-Scholes equation). In the case where $P$ pays a single cashflow $P(T,S_T)$ at $T$, the Feynman-Kac theorem ensures that the solution to this PDE can be written as an expectation
\begin{eqnarray*}
  P(t,S) &=& \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[ e^{-\int_t^T r ds} P(T,Y_T) |Y_t = S\right] 
\end{eqnarray*}
where $(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is any probability space, $W^\mathbb{Q}$ a Brownian motion on it and $Y$ a process satisfying the SDE
$$
  \frac{dY_t}{Y_t} = (r-q) dt + \sigma dW^\mathbb{Q}_t
$$
Such a probability $\mathbb{Q}$ is usuallly called the risk-neutral measure and the process $Y$ is usually written $S$. But they are only mathematical constructs that can make computation easier because the real-world drift is irrelevant. The core of the argument is accounting for the PnL of our strategy and absence of arbitrage. The fact that the price does not depend on the drift is due to the fact that it cancels out when we hold the underlying as our hedge.

Comment: In this writeup, the knowledge about the dividend $q$ is represented in a two rule discrete time stepping representation of the state of $\Pi_t$, and then the stock process is represented without knowledge of $q$ as $dS=S(\mu dt+\sigma dW)$.  This form of $dS$ doesn't represent the market's continuous deflation of the price of a dividend-paying stock by the rate of payout. If you only watched the price of $S_t$, you wouldn't see dividend deflation.  Other writeups sometimes put $q$ in $dS$ as $dS=S((\mu-q)dt+\sigma dW)$, which will show the deflation but maybe confuse the rule for $d\Pi$.

Comment: @ AFK: Is it true that $\Pi_0=0$?